# ¿Comando para ejecutar y cerrar aplicación tras un tiempo?

Tags: linux

He estado teniendo algunos problemas con la ejecución de Spring Tool Suite en Elementary OS Loki 0.4 que esta basado en Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

El problema es que la PC deja de responder debido a que la aplicacion comienza a consumir toda la RAM de la PC después de unos segundos de haber iniciado la aplicación, cuento con i3 5005u y 8GB RAM por lo que creo el problema no es la PC si no algo mismo del sistema.

La pregunta es, ¿Existe algún comando desde la terminal para ejecutar una aplicación y programar su propio cierre antes de que colapse o tras determinado tiempo o algún comando para ejecutar la aplicación solo dándole acceso a una cantidad determinada de RAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para limitar los recursos de los procesos tienes la herramienta `ulimit`.

Si la ejecutas con el parámetro `-a` te dice los límites actuales para el proceso actual (la shell que interpreta tus órdenes):

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 31605
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 31605
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Lo que buscas es el parámetro `-v` que configura el límite de uso de memoria (en KiB).

Si quieres limitar el uso de memoria a 2 GiB de memoria puedes ejecutar:

```
ulimit -v 2048
```

O también:

```
ulimit -v $((2 * 1024))
```

Con eso cualquier comando que ejecutes a partir de ese momento (sólo durante esa sesión de shell) tendrá un límite de uso de memoria de 2 GiB:

```
$ ulimit -a | grep "^virtual memory"
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 2048
```

Si quieres hacer los cambios persistentes deberás mirar el [manual de  `limits.conf`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf).

Edición: El límite de memoria se refiere a la memoria solicitada al sistema operativo. Ésta puede estar almacenada en memoria física (RAM) y/o el archivo de intercambio (swap).